# URL rewriting using htaccess gives 500 internal server error in subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I'm using this code to rewrite in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

It works fine in **`example.com/sub`** , but in **`sub.example.com`** it gives `500 internal server error` (except for the landing page).

I can't understand what wrong here. Sometimes it may be very simple. I'm using GoDaddy.

Error log.

```
[Tue Feb 11 00:32:51 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.192.156:15900] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Feb 12 03:03:37 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.232.6:16075] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://sub.example.com/
[Wed Feb 12 03:03:37 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.232.6:16069] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://sub.example.com/
[Wed Feb 12 03:03:37 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.232.6:16079] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://sub.example.com/
[Wed Feb 12 03:03:38 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.232.6:16081] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://sub.example.com/
[Wed Feb 12 03:03:40 2014] [11333226] [core:error] [client 122.174.232.6:16082] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer http://sub.example.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for me.

Comment: This was a huge help. Just ran into a situation where my .htaccess was erroring out. I'm working within a subdomain so setting the `RewriteBase` was crucial. +1 my friend. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Still showing 500 internal server error...

Comment: You need to check your Apache error.log since there is no syntax error here.

Comment: I can't access those files...

Comment: Without concrete info I don't think anyone can guess it. This code is fine and I have tested it.

Comment: This code is similar to mine. You just added one more rewrite condition( to directories ).

Comment: See carefully. There are 2 negative conditions to prevent looping.

Comment: If you're still getting looping with this code then I suspect there are some other rules in some other .htaccess also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, even with .htaccess written properly.  Took me a moment to realize the file permissions were wrong.  Doh!!!

**IMPORTANT:** PHP files must not have 777 permissions. If you are trying to open a PHP file that has such permissions, it will result in an "Internal Server Error 500". To resolve the problem, simply change the permissions of the file to 644 or 755.